# $\gcd\left(n, \binom{n}{m}\right) = \frac{n}{\gcd(n, m)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that $$\frac{\gcd(n, m)}{n}\binom{n}{m} \in \mathbb{Z}$$ using the following lemma:

> $$\gcd\left(n, \binom{n}{m}\right) = \frac{n}{\gcd(n, m)}$$

I was able to show that the RHS divides the LHS of the lemma which was enough to prove the question. However, is the title statement even true?

Comment: I think it can be proved by looking at the factorizations of $n$, RHS, and LHS of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(60,%5Cbinom%7B60%7D%7B30%7D)

Wolfram alpha tells $\gcd\left(60, \binom{60}{30}\right) = 4$, while $\frac{60}{\gcd(60, 30)}=2$. So the statement is not true?

Another table: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(gcd(360,%5Cbinom%7B360%7D%7Bm%7D))%2F(360%2Fgcd(360,m))+from+m%3D1+to+360